# understanding MVC in simple words

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i checked google, books etc but all defines it differently and made me highly confused. Please describe it simply that what parts does what and contains what or can ?

Comment: what don't you understand?

Comment: do you understand any of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets start with
CONTROLLER:
MVC always start with the CONTROLLER. its connects your VIEW and your MODEL. CONTROLLERS are responsible for your business logic like validation, computations, etc.

MODEL:
responsible for obtaining/storing data in your database.

VIEW:
displays data, your User interface.

Answer (score 0):

> The Model-View-Controller as it implies contains three components when
>   this model is implemented:
>
> The Model - This should take care of all the operations which deal
>   with the data required (in other words the business logic) for the
>   application, which is implementing the MVC model from now onwards will
>   be referred to as by the MVC application. The operations can mean
>   reading, writing data into the database, getting information from
>   remote machines via network, time consuming operations etc. The model
>   should also inform the view about any changes to the data happening in
>   the background. The View - This component takes care of presenting the
>   data to the user. With respect to the context of this article, i.e.,
>   WinForms, the view class will be tied around with the Form which will
>   be shown to the user. The Controller - This is the center and
>   important component of the MVC pattern as it ties the Model and View
>   together. The Model which manipulates the data and the View which
>   presents the data to the user does not know the existence of each
>   other or they interact directly with each other. It is the controller
>   which acts as an intermediary and ties them together. For example, the
>   controller takes the input from the user such as a button click and
>   informs the model to take appropriate action, if there should be an
>   action that needs to be initiated to manipulate the project data.

[image]

[Check here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/613682/Your-first-program-using-MVC-pattern-with-Csharp-W)

Answer (score 0):

1. The **View** is the parts of the application that handles the display of the data.
   You can say it GUI of your web application. It donot have any logic say database conenction logic.For example , if you want to display list of students from the DB , one way is  put the select query in the .asp.,.cshtml,.vbhtml file and show the reult there . But in MVC view will have code of displaying recodes and model will have the code fore retriving it. Most often the views are created from the model data.
2. The **Model** is the part of the application that handles the logic for the application data.
   Often model objects retrieve data (and store data) from a database.
3. The **Controller** is the part of the application that handles user interaction.
   Typically controllers read data from a view, control user input, and send input data to the model.
   It connect the  view to model , model to view and user request for some page to view.
   When user enter the url like ".../Home/Index" then it goes to the Controller  first . There can be many controllers , here it will go to "Home" controller class and in that class it will call the "Index" action or say "method". That method will return the "Index.cshtml/Index.vbhtml/Index.asp" view back to user as response.

MVC seperate tha main logic from the view and controller is the one who handel those.